# I want to insert database value in grid view editable text box from which I can update that text box

Tags: asp.net, gridview, visual-studio-2008

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdAttendance1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
                        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="InstID" HeaderText="College ID" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Fid" HeaderText="Employee ID" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="FName" HeaderText="Employee Name" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Designation" HeaderText="Designation" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="In Time">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtIntime1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Out Time">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtOuttime1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Leave Type">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLeaveType1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                             </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
                    </asp:GridView>
```

I took this but it is not binding with database text box is showing blank.

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend browsing [Microsoft's ASP.NET data access tutorials](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access)

**I'll give you a general guide to set you on the right track**

1. Add a command field like this: `<asp:CommandField ButtonType=”Link” ShowEditButton=”true” 
   ShowDeleteButton=”true”  ShowCancelButton=”true” />`
2. Set whatever fields you do not want to be editable to `readonly="true"`
3. Add `EditItemTemplates` for editable template fields.
4. Fill in your event handlers, such as editindexchanged, updating, deleted, edit-canceled, etc. [See GV Events here (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview_events.aspx)

   - Implement your save-to-DB code in the Row_Updating event.

This can be a little tricky to do for the first time, but once you have it down it's pretty easy.